# Why check if your popoverController is nil? Doesn't Obj-C ignore messages to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Pretty much [everyone that writes about the UISplitView on the iPad](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=if+(popoverController+!%3D+nil)) uses the following code structure to dismiss a popover:

```
if (popoverController != nil) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

I though Objective-C was happy to ignore messages that are passed to nil? In fact, in the File > New Project > New Split View Application template, there's an example of this shortcut in the same code block (DetailsViewController.m):

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem { 
    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        [detailItem release];                             //might be nil
        detailItem = [newDetailItem retain]; 

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }


    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];   //was checked for nil
    }        
}
```

Why is that second if necessary?

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary. Nil-checking is for communists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's not important and just adds a line of code.

<strike>However, when the return type of a method is not an integral type, this check can be important. Oh crap, it seems they fixed that in ObjC 2.0.</strike>

It's important to check for `nil` when a non-scalar type should be returned. Take this example:

```
struct complex_t
{
    int foo, bar, frob;
    double nicate;
};

@interface Foo : NSObject {}
-(struct complex_t)complex;
@end

@implementation Foo
-(struct complex_t)complex { return (struct complex_t){-1, 2, -1, 1e14}; }
@end

int main()
{
    struct complex_t c;
    memset(&c, 0xFFFFFFFF, sizeof c);
    c = [nil complex];
    printf("%i %i %i %g\n", c.foo, c.bar, c.frob, c.nicate);
}
```

In this example, our `c` is happily memset to have `-1`s in every field (except for the double, which I don't quite know what it does). Messaging `nil` indeed resets everything to zero.

But wait!

Just suppose we change our `main` a little bit:

```
int main()
{
    struct complex_t c;
    memset(&c, 0xFFFFFFFF, sizeof c);
    [[[Foo alloc] init] complex]; // NEW LINE HERE!
    c = [nil complex];
    printf("%i %i %i %g\n", c.foo, c.bar, c.frob, c.nicate);
}
```

It now happens that `c` will hold what `[[[Foo alloc] init] complex]` returned, even though the return value was technically not used. (**EDIT** Compiled from `gcc -lobjc -framework Cocoa` as an x86_64 binary. Your mileage may vary with your architecture.)

It seems the return value of a big `struct` when messaging `nil` is undefined.

Comment: +1 sending a message to `nil` and expecting a struct as a response can result in garbage.  In this case, checking for `nil` is a good idea.

Comment: @bbum: I know. It's the first thing I wrote: _In this case, it's not important and it just adds a line of code._ It's just you shouldn't think that it's always, systematically fine to message `nil` without checking.

Comment: Bonus point for such a thorough answer!  You are absolutely correct that it is important to know when it isn't safe.  Usually, I draw the line at "is the return value used or not".  If so, always test and always show that you have thought the nil case through and have explicitly picked a value.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't necessary.   File a bug.

Comment: I don't think it deserves a _bug report_.

Comment: The existence of this question is proof positive that there that the inconsistency has a related (and unnecessary) expense.  Minor? Absolutely.  But... well... death by 1000 cuts and all.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it's not.  I guess some people like to be explicit...?